# How to create a new file inside web content by FileOutputStream

Tags: java

Here I'am trying to append some text (variable addedContent) in the existing file (i.e Agreement_doc.pdf) and trying to create a new PDF (i.e `test.pdf`) inside WebContent which is not getting created but if I'm trying to create it my local system by giving path `C:\\Users\\Anshuman\\Desktop\\test.pdf`, it's successfully getting created.

Why is it so and how can I create file to my localhost's webcontent.

```
package com.pdf;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.lowagie.text.*;

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;

public class AddPage {

    public static void generatePDF(String newPdfName, String addedContent) {
        try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("http://localhost:8080//apnaOffice//pdf//Agreement_doc.pdf");
            PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("text.pdf"));
            PdfContentByte over;
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            over = stamp.getOverContent(9);
            over.beginText();
            over.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
            over.setColorFill(new Color(0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
            over.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, addedContent, 72, 360, 0);
            over.endText();
            stamp.close();
        } catch (Exception de) {
            de.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not getting an exception the file was written successfully - but I think not in the place you're expecting it. Try to search for the file text.pdf in your file system. Can you find it?

Comment: No,It's not there.
I've also tried to change the Path
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("/WebContent/test.pdf"));
Now It's showing the exception 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \WebContent\test.pdf (The system cannot find the path specified)